# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1Error:

Tags: flutter, exception, package, widget, execution

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/paginated_data_table.dart:556:26: Error: A value of type '({LayoutBuilder child, bool semanticContainer})' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Widget'.

- 'LayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  semanticContainer: false,
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:25: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'elevation'.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:46: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'elevation'.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'color' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:119:16: Context: 'color' is defined here.
  final Color? color;
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'shadowColor' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:126:16: Context: 'shadowColor' is defined here.
  final Color? shadowColor;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'surfaceTintColor' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:138:16: Context: 'surfaceTintColor' is defined here.
  final Color? surfaceTintColor;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'elevation' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:147:17: Context: 'elevation' is defined here.
  final double? elevation;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'shape' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:157:22: Context: 'shape' is defined here.
  final ShapeBorder? shape;
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'borderOnForeground' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:163:14: Context: 'borderOnForeground' is defined here.
  final bool borderOnForeground;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'margin' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:178:29: Context: 'margin' is defined here.
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;
  ^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'clipBehavior' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:169:15: Context: 'clipBehavior' is defined here.
  final Clip? clipBehavior;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'child' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:196:17: Context: 'child' is defined here.
  final Widget? child;
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Error: Final field 'semanticContainer' is not initialized by this constructor.
  Try to initialize the field using an initializing formal or a field initializer.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:191:14: Context: 'semanticContainer' is defined here.
  final bool semanticContainer;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/about.dart:1471:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'color'.
  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card.dart:65:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Card() : assert(elevation == null || elevation >= 0.0),
  ^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried open new flutter project
I tried flutter doctor
Nothing worked out to execute output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.